# Spying on class which is in constructor fails to record received method call

Tags: laravel, mocking

What I want to do, is to assert that a class's method was called during a request. The code will probably explain better what I'm trying to do:

Test:

```
public function use_default_provider_when_getting_addresses()
{
    $spy = $this->spy(CraftyClicksService::class);
    $this->app->bind(CraftyClicksService::class, function () use ($spy) {
        return $spy;
    });

    $addresses = $this->get('/api/v1/address?postcode=POSTCODE')->decodeResponseJson();

    $this->assertTrue(in_array([
        'line_1' => 'Line 1',
        'line_2' => 'Line 2',
        'postcode' => 'POSTCODE',
    ], $addresses));

    $spy->shouldHaveReceived('getAddresses')->once();
}
```

The request hits a simple controller:

```
    public function show(Request $request, AddressService $addressService)
    {
        return $addressService->findAddress($request->input('postcode'));
    }
```

The address service class (for now) then calls another class's function to retrieve the addresses.

```
class AddressService
{
    protected CraftyClicksService $craftyClicksService;

    /**
     * AddressService constructor.
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->craftyClicksService = new CraftyClicksService();
    }

    /**
     * @param string $postcode
     * @return array
     */
    public function findAddress(string $postcode)
    {
        return $this->craftyClicksService->getAddresses($postcode);
    }
```

I can 'spy' on the AddressService class and assert it received the `findAddress` method, however it seems I cant assert the `getAddresses` function for the `CraftyClicksService` class.

I always get a `Method getAddresses(<Any Arguments>) from Mockery_3_App_Services_CraftyClicksService should be called at least 1 times but called 0 times.` error, even though the response test passes and I can confirm that method is indeed the one called.

Tried to use the `$this->app->bind` as well as the `$this->spy()` but test still fails.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use dependency injection and let the service container resolve the dependency from the container so the AddressService class should change to

```
class AddressService
{
    protected CraftyClicksService $craftyClicksService;

    /**
     * AddressService constructor.
     */
    public function __construct(CraftyClicksService $CraftyClicksService)
    {
        $this->craftyClicksService = $CraftyClicksService;
    }

    /**
     * @param string $postcode
     * @return array
     */
    public function findAddress(string $postcode)
    {
        return $this->craftyClicksService->getAddresses($postcode);
    }
```

This way, the spy object which you have bound it to the container will be used.